# How to set and retrieve pixels from a Bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap

Why is the following conditional failing?

```
brush = new Bitmap(10, 10);
brush.SetPixel(1, 1, Color.Black);
if (brush.GetPixel(1, 1) == Color.Black)
{          
    MessageBox.Show("hello");
}

// Will not show "hello"
```

Comment: what is the value of `brush.GetPixel(1,1)`? Have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pixel is indeed black, but it seems to fail because `Color.Black` is a `KnownColor` and `NamedColor` while `ff000000` (the result of your GetPixel) is not. You can change the condition to verify directly the ARGB values instead :

```
if (brush.GetPixel(1, 1).ToArgb() == Color.Black.ToArgb())
{          
    MessageBox.Show("hello");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre - you're right and it indeed solved my problem!

Comment: @Pierre - Can you please elaborate that why GetPixel retunrs UnknownColor if we explicitly set it to KnonwColor?

Comment: @RohitVats That's a pretty good question, and sadly I does not have an answer for that. In my opinion black is such a basic color (and the hex code is also correct) so it should indeed be converted correctly to `KnownColor`. I have no idea why it isn't recognized.

Comment: @SJuan76 Do I do so by clicking the "V" sign on the left? It says "accepted answer" not "correct"

Comment: Color of pixel is stored as `int` and converts to `Color` via `Color.FromArgb` method and this method always sets `KnownColor` to 0 = UnknownColor

Answer (score 0):

The == operator has following definition:

```
public static bool operator ==(Color left, Color right)
{
  if (left.value != right.value || (int) left.state != (int) right.state || (int) left.knownColor != (int) right.knownColor)
    return false;
  if (left.name == right.name)
    return true;
  if (left.name == null || right.name == null)
    return false;
  else
    return left.name.Equals(right.name);
}
```

If you look at `Color.Black` and `result from GetPixel` in debug mode you will see differences.

Comment: Thanks - I can only see the prototype, but not the definition (I'm pressing F12 -> Go to Definition. It is reading from MetaData). Where do you see this implementation?

Comment: I using ReSharper which automatically download pdb file from Microsoft Reference Source and decompile it. In VS you can enable this feature in menu Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols